# Asynctask read xml parallely in viewpager get crashed in android

Tags: android-fragments, android-asynctask, android-viewpager, swipe

I use xml parser to read asynctask parallel (multiple thread) in viewpager.
Here my problem is while I swipe my viewpager fastly app get crashed.
Here is my code

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh(final int n) {
    final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7);
    //final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(n);
     t=new Thread(){

        @Override
        public void run() {
            this.setPriority(10);
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB){
                load =new LoadWebPageASYNC(n);
                load.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
                }else{
                load=new LoadWebPageASYNC(n);
                load.execute();}
            } 
    };
    t.setPriority(10);
    es.execute(t);
}
```

Could you please help me what I am gets wrong. 
I think the problem is with update current fragment. 
I am new to android so please guide me for right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand why you are creating a thread pool and then start single new Thread. At first sight it seems you do not want to call final ExecutorService es = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(7); every time you call doTheAutoRefresh

do you start a new Thread in LoadWebPageASYNC(n) as well ?

Maybe you can post the error message and a bit more code.

kind regards
Anton

Comment: my code running perfect.how were get this error.Run-time exception here.

Comment: 06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1376)
06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:595)

Comment: 06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:415)
06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-25 18:44:48.347: E/AndroidRuntime(676):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)